# How to list Firebase data filtered by date?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, filter, datetimepicker

I want to list firebase data on page filtered by date

DatePicker to select date:

```
{
  DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    locale: const Locale("tr", "TR"),
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: DateTime(2000),
    lastDate: DateTime(2100),
  );
  if (pickedDate != null) {
    print(pickedDate); 
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(pickedDate);
    print(formattedDate); 
   
    setState(() {
      tarihfiltre.text = formattedDate;
      tarih = pickedDate;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the code I wrote for these other filters:

```
FirestoreListView<Map<String, dynamic>>(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  query: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('odemeler'),
  itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
    Map<String, dynamic> odeme = snapshot.data();
    if (searchString == '' ||
        odeme['firma'].toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase()) ||
        odeme['alici'].toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase()) ||
        odeme['odeme'].toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase()) ||
        odeme['bitis'] == tarih) {
      return Column(children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        // Expanded(
        //   child: FutureBuilder(
        //     // Our existing list code
        //   ),
        // ),

        SizedBox(...
...)
```

```
odeme['bitis'] == tarih)
```

The above line is the code I tried for filtering by date, but it doesn't work.

How can I specify and list the data that is on the same date as the date I selected from the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderBy or Where clause to filter your data from firestore.

According to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) you should use the where method. Combine that with [firebase flutter docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) (relevant example [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference)), you should be able to accomplish this using something like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('odemeler')
  .where('bitis', isEqualTo: 'tarih')
  .where(...) //another where condition
```